# Apache Flink, Job with big grap - submisson times out on cluster

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

We trying to build Flink Job for price aggregation with quite complicated logic.

E.g. previous version had a graph as below.

After another development iteration, I added even more complexity to the job.
The new version was running fine from IDE, however, deployment to cluster fails with

> Caused by: org.apache.flink.runtime.client.JobClientActorSubmissionTimeoutException: Job submission to the JobManager timed out.

If I reconfigure the job (reduce graph complexity) it gets deployed without any problem.

My questions are:

1. Are there any limitations on Job Graph size and complexity when submitting to standalone cluster?
2. Is there any possibility to disable graphical graph representation (I have suspicions that the problem is caused by Graph view - locally my job works)
3. Are there any debug tools, to understand what is happening on the Job submission, and why it times out?

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Which version of Flink are you using? Is this problem still there with Flink 1.5? If so, could you please share the cli and cluster logs with us?

Comment: @TillRohtmann We were using flink 1.4.1, but upgrade to 1.5 solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to use latest flink version (1.5 at the time of writing).